# MicroPython usockets not timing out

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, blocking, micropython

For various reasons, I am trying to have my ESP32 device with MicroPython poll all 256 options of 192.168.1.*:79 to find a 'host' PC. In doing so, the ESP32 attempts to create a socket and connect it to each possible address, i.e.:

```
while not connected:
  try:
    addr = generate_next_address()
    s = usocket.socket()
    s.connect(addr)
  except OSError:
    s.close()
    continue
  print("Found a connection!")
  connected = True
```

When attempting to send a connection to a device that refuses the `connect()`, it is very quick to throw the exception and move onward. However, the problem is when it starts encountering devices that either don't respond or don't exist, it waits for a significant time before timing out.

Now, I've tried every variation of using `usocket.settimeout()`, `usocket.setblocking()`, `uselect.poll()`, and `time.delay()`, but I was unable to get anything to change the timeout period.

By setting blocking to false, the script immediately attempts all 256 addresses and then breaks out of the while loop, disallowing an opportunity to connect properly. Having blocking on completely ignores any timeout setting I attempt, continuing to take 15-20 seconds to timeout, as opposed to 1.

Is there something I'm not understanding about how this works? Is there a solution that is obvious but I have missed?